# NSUserDefaults not being saved in simulator ,even though I use synchronize

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I add a dictionary to NSUserDefaults and call 'synchronize' method,but when I close my app and reopen it the values which are saved in NSUserDefault are nil.

```
#define kStartTime @"startTime"
#define kEndTime @"endTime"
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *startTime=@"08:00";
NSString *endTime=@"18:00";
NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:startTime,kStartTime,
                           endTime,kEndTime,
                            nil];
[defaults registerDefaults:dict];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` method I call this:

```
NSString *startTimeValue=[defaults stringForKey:kStartTime];
```

the startTimeValue is still nil When I reopen my app in simulator.Is UserDefaults can't save in Simulator???

**My point is when i close my app and reopen it in simulator the values are gone.**

After I searched the apple document ,I got this.

`registerDefaults:`.

As is said in Apple Document :Adds the contents of the specified dictionary to the registration domain.

**The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk;**you need to call this method each time your application starts.You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory and call registerDefaults: with the contents that you read in from that file.

**So the function of the `registerDefaults:` is setting Default values in app,The Default value will not stored in disk by `synchronize`**

Comment: check my updated answer... just copy it and run you get the values...

Comment: Try to save whole dict like: [defaults setValue:dict forKey:@"dictionary"]; and fetch it like this: NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; and dict=[defaults valueForKey:@"dictionary"];

Comment: i just edited your code and work fine check it....

Comment: Just an FYI, synchronize should not be called explicitly unless you need to pick up changes made through Settings.app.

Comment: Go to /users/USER_NAME/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Applications/APP_KEY/Library/Preferences/. There if you have *.plist file that means you saved your data correcctly. You can open this file and check if data is correct.

Comment: @lvp the content of plist file under Preferences is Garbled when i open it in vim

Comment: in which method do you register your defaults?

Comment: @JitendraDeore I know it,But My point is when i close my app and reopen it the values are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to read the value from NSUserDefaults before you have registered the defaults. 
If you register defaults these values are not saved to disk, they will not persist to the next application launch. You have to register the default values every time you launch the app.

When you read an object from NSUserDefaults and you have not saved a value before, the registered default value will be returned. If you have saved a value before, this value will be returned.

In the code you posted you have not saved anything to userDefaults. So the value you have registered as default will be returned. If you haven't registered any values this will return nil.

The code that registers the defaults should be put in a method that runs very early in the application life cycle. I would recommend to use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

**If you want to save multiple values to NSUserDefaults you have to use multiple `setObject:forKey:` calls.

`registerDefaults:` can not be used to save multiple keys to NSUserDefaults at the same time!**

Comment: It really works for me! I replace  `registerDefaults:` with `SetObject:forKey:` . :)

Comment: The registerDefaults can save multiple keys to NSUserDefaults. The problem lies in the `registerDefaults:`.As is said in Apple Document :Adds the contents of the specified dictionary to the registration domain. **The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts**

Answer (score -1):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:startTime,@"kStartTime",
                        endTime,@"kEndTime",
                        nil];
    [defaults registerDefaults:dict];
    [defaults synchronize];


    NSString *startTimeValue=[defaults stringForKey:@"kStartTime"];

    NSLog(@"%@",startTimeValue);
```

you need to add keys like @"value"  like this.

Now try this code....

Comment: If kEndTime is a constants why would you need to do this @"kEndTime" as the key?

Comment: thanks, but the `kStartTime ` is a `#define kStartTime  @"###"` and I just forgot to paste it out. I will edit it soon.